# "Unrecoverable error" during installation

Tags: 11.04, installation

I have an old Dell computer and I want to switch from windows xp and install the new ubuntu. I have tried multiple times to download it via cd-r but keep getting the same error message: unrecoverable error.

The error happens after the menu which lists try ubuntu, install ubuntu, etc.It only gets as far as the Screen with a toolbar on the top that includes power, sound, and two arrows. That is when the message displays. switching to desktop version to find what the problem is( or something like that.)

What is going wrong?

Comment: During what step do you get this error?

Comment: After the menu which lists try ubuntu, install ubuntu, etc.It only gets as far as the Screen with a toolbar on the top that includes power, sound, and two arrows. That is when the message displays.

Comment: Should I also clear the hard drive of windows xp to ensure nothing goes wrong?

Comment: no, thats not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Download [ubuntu alternative installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download) and install with that.

Be advised that there is no guarantee that the same thing won't happen again after you install it.. but at least you'll get that far.