# "The installer encountered an unrecoverable error" while installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from CD

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04LTS on an old machine that I fixed up.  It boots from CD fine, it partitions the drive, and it gets about 25% copying files, and then I get this error:

> The installer encountered an unrecoverable error. A desktop session will now be run so that you may investigate the problem or try installing again.

I'm thinking it might be a bad CD, I tried burning another CD, but it does the same.  The system had 11.10 on it prior, and it ran fine, up until this point.  What can be the cause of this?

System Specs:

- Intel PIII 1.0Ghz
- 512GB RAM
- 80GB HD
- Onboard VGA

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/145437/12864) and [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/54711/12864)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Alternate Installer](http://mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net/ubuntu-releases/12.04/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso).

I encountered the same message some weeks ago, and installing with the Alternate Ubuntu Installer helped a lot.

The only difference is that the installation is in text mode. I think the problem is a graphics bug.